# Docker alpine golang go get error for coding.net private repo

Tags: git, go, docker

I created the private repository using the coding.net.
I use docker images **alpine** and **centos**.
I can go get `git.coding.net/alphayan/orionv2.git successful` from docker-centos, but I can't go get `git.coding.net/alphayan/test.git` from docker-alpine.It returns an error stating:

```
/go/src # go get -u -v  git.coding.net/alphayan/test.git
# cd .; git ls-remote https://git.coding.net/alphayan/test
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.coding.net': terminal prompts disabled
# cd .; git ls-remote git+ssh://git.coding.net/alphayan/test
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
# cd .; git ls-remote ssh://git.coding.net/alphayan/test
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
package git.coding.net/alphayan/test.git: cannot download, git.coding.net/alphayan/test uses insecure protocol
```

From centos it let me use the username and password:

```
[root@83fc8067fc95 /]# go get -u -v git.coding.net/alphayan/test.git
Username for 'https://git.coding.net':
```

finally, I find it caused by the git's version, the centos with git 1.8.3 and the alpine with git 2.11.0.
then I change the centos git's version with 2.11.0, becomes the same wrong with alpine.
I think I can modify golang or git source file solve this problem,
could someone help me? thinks~!

Comment: what's the error ?? also it looks like you have a private git repo

Comment: use alpine，the git's version is  2.11,it don't take me input username and password,and then i can't go get the code;but use centos ,the git's version is 1.8.3,it  hint me input the username and password,then i get the code. i change the git version 2.11 to centos,it will be the same thing like alpine.i find it's the git's error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens because by default `go get` [doesn't use terminal input](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/16091/). This behaviour can be changed by modifying environment variable `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT`, which was introduced in git 2.3. That's why the `go get` command behaves differently in CentOS 7 (git 1.8) and Alpine 3.5 (git 2.11).

You can work your way around the issue in `git >= 2.3` by running `go get` as follows:

```
$ GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/foo/bar
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

If you have multiple `go get` calls then you can export that environment variable before running the commands:

```
$ export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
$ go get github.com/foo/bar
Username for 'https://github.com':
$ go get github.com/foo/baz
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You could try through ssh, if your [public ssh key is registered on coding.net](https://coding.net/help/doc/git/ssh-key.html).

See "[go get for private repos in docker](https://divan.github.io/posts/go_get_private/)" as an example:

```
FROM golang:1.6

RUN echo "[url \"git@github.com:\"]\n\tinsteadOf = https://github.com/" >> /root/.gitconfig
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no " > /root/.ssh/config
ADD .  /go/src/github.com/company/foo
CMD cd /go/src/github.com/company/foo && go get github.com/company/bar && go build -o /foo
```

with the build step:

```
docker build -t foo-build .
docker run --name=foo-build -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa foo-build
docker cp foo-build:/foo foo
docker rm -f foo-build
docker rmi -f foo-build
```

Comment: yes ,through ssh it will be right.i find that  after the git version 1.8.4  ,the   `go get`  can't  get  code  successful from a private repo.but use `git clone ` it will get  the code. i don't  know  it's  the git's or golang's  bug.

Comment: @alphayan I don't know either, but if that allows to move forward, this answer could be a solution.